# ValueError: shapes (1,1) and (4,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 4 (dim 0)

Tags: python, matrix

So I am trying to implement (a * b) * (M * a.T) but I keep getting ValueError. As I am new to python and numpy functions, help would be great. Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy.matlib
import numpy as np



def complicated_matrix_function(M, a, b):

    ans1 = np.dot(a, b)
    ans2 = np.dot(M, a.T)
    out = np.dot(ans1, ans2)

    return out

M = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])
a = np.array([[1, 1, 0]])
b = np.array([[-1], [2], [5]])

ans = complicated_matrix_function(M, a, b)

print(ans)
print()
print("The size is: ", ans.shape)
```

The error message is:

> ValueError: shapes (1,1) and (4,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 4 (dim 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you that `numpy.dot` does not know what to do with a (1x1) matrix and a (4x1) matrix. However, since in your formula you only say that you want to multiply, I assume, that you just want to multiply the scalar from the scalar product (a,b) to be multiplied with the vector coming out of the matrix-vector product (M.a). For this, you can simply use `*` in python.

So your example would be:

```py
import numpy.matlib
    import numpy as np

    def complicated_matrix_function(M, a, b):

        ans1 = np.dot(a, b)
        ans2 = np.dot(M, a.T)
        out = ans1 * ans2

        return out

    M = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])
    a = np.array([[1, 1, 0]])
    b = np.array([[-1], [2], [5]])

    ans = complicated_matrix_function(M, a, b)

    print(ans)
    print()
    print("The size is: ", ans.shape)
```

resulting in

```
[[ 3]
 [ 9]
 [15]
 [21]]

The size is:  (4, 1)
```

**Note**

Note that `numpy.dot` will do a lot of `interpretation` to figure out what you want to do. So if you do not need your result to be of size (4,1), you can simplify everything to:

```py
import numpy.matlib
import numpy as np



def complicated_matrix_function(M, a, b):

    ans1 = np.dot(a, b)
    ans2 = np.dot(M, a) # no transpose required
    out = ans1 * ans2

    return out

M = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])
a = np.array([1, 1, 0]) # no extra [] required
b = np.array([-1, 2, 5]) # no extra [] required

ans = complicated_matrix_function(M, a, b)

print(ans)
print()
print("The size is: ", ans.shape)
```

resulting in

```
[ 3  9 15 21]

The size is:  (4,)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and well defined response!

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. If this solves your problem you can mark it as such, so that others know that this question is solved. If you think it is a good answer, you can also upvote it.